# External USB driver not working sitecom WL3001

Tags: drivers, usb

Since I had issues with my internal wireless card I decided to buy an external one. The shop advised me the WII USB ADAPTER AC-450 WL 3001.

So I inserted the dongle but it does not recognize it.

The output of `lsub` is:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 064e:c341 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0df6:0079 Sitecom Europe B.V. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Now my question is, how could I make it work?

Thanks very much